# How to add specific path to CLASSPATH on OS X 10.8?

Tags: java, classpath, osx-mountain-lion

OS X ignores CLASSPATH, I've added following line to the `.bash_profile`:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path:/anOtherPath
```

when `echo $CLSSPATH` I can see provided path but OS X is looking for jars only in `/Library/Java/Extensions` and appropriated path in `~`.

**How to add specific path to CLASSPATH?**

Comment: If my answer solved your problem can you accept it so that other's will know it's reliable?

Comment: @DavidC.Sainte-Claire but it's not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that I've heard of people doing, including adding the new directories to ~/.bash_profile or editing /etc/profile.

That said, what I generally do is to create a file inside /etc/paths.d that has the directories that I want to add to my PATH.  If you look at /etc/paths then you can see the format (basically just add the fully-qualified path to each directory that you want to add on its own line in the file).  For example, I have a file called android inside the /etc/paths.d directory that has the path to the Android platform-tools folder and also to my NDK folder, because I use them both for Android work.

You could just edit the file /etc/paths but I wouldn't recommend it because that's a system path, and Apple can overwrite it at will if they push a new update to you.  paths.d is safer.